# show nav icon if open in small resolution or mobile vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i have issue how to show nav icon if open in mobile screen,
this is the code is bellow

```
export default {
  data () {
      return {
        navIcon:false
      }
  },
  computed:{

  },
  methods:{
    reversedMessage: function () {
      return this.navIcon=true
    },
    test:function(){
      if(screen.width < 960){
        return this.navIcon=true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this should be done with css

Answer (score 0):

Use media breakpoints in CSS or if you don't want to go in that direction just use this plugin of vue **vue-breakpoints** . It will save your time as well on applying logics. Use show-at and hide-at with breakpoints according to your requirement